# Python 2.x IDLE Unicode font not showing when using lxml

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, lxml

When I using lxml library in python to get data on a html page (Youtube video title), It not return text correctly It return a text  Like this "à·à·à¶½à¶±à·à¶§à¶ºà¶±à"

Here my code,

```
page = requests.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MZMapfEg5g8")
source = html.fromstring(page.content)
links = source.xpath('//link[@type="text/xml+oembed"]')
for href in links:
    return href.attrib['title']
```

Language I need is is in sinhala, and it's unicode.

Comment: That isn't your exact or complete code (you have a `return` statement but no function shown). Please edit your question to include a runnable example that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
source = html.fromstring(page.text)
```

With the requests library, `page.text` will be the decoded text.  `page.content` is the raw byte content, and `page.encoding` is the encoding of the page.

In summary:

```
import requests
from lxml import html
page = requests.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MZMapfEg5g8")
source = html.fromstring(page.text)
links = source.xpath('//link[@type="text/xml+oembed"]')
for href in links:
    print href.attrib['title']
```

Output (requires terminal/IDE that supports the characters/font):

```
පේස් බුක් මැසේජ් එක (Facebook Messege)
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the title you get is a byte string, you need to `.decode()` it to turn into Unicode. The title in question, "පේස් බුක් මැසේජ් එක", when encoded as UTF-8 and *then* decoded / displayed as Latin-1, gives the output you complain about.

A simple `.decode('utf-8')` should fix the problem.